# Which end of a capstan has the higher tension?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, string

Which end of a capstan has the higher tension? I mean, how does the rope know that on which end , the higher force has to be applied to the keep the rope stationary?[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capstan_equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter which end of the rope is under higher tension. Since the static friction force acts in the direction that prevents slipping, the effect of static friction will be to increase the tension force in the rope from the side at lower tension to the side at higher tension, regardless of which side is which.

Comment: Wow, really well said. +1. That is very clear, slipping will always be in the direction of the higher tension, so the friction will always act in the opposite direction.

Comment: I think I get what you said. Just to make sure - what you want to say is that friction will set itself in such a direction that whichever side that *requires* higher tension to prevent slipping will *get*/receive the required tension? am i right?

Comment: @AkarshSahay Yes, exactly.